# Actions on Google smart home Experience?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-home, google-smart-home

I'm thinking about building a smart home, where i can Switch the lights on/off with my google home. I want to use a Raspberry Pi or similar, which is controlling a relais.  I saw this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdZXpFBvTP8), where they show exactly this setup. They make it seem easy. Is there anywhere a tutorial, where they dig deeper in the matter? Or has anyone experience with this? Up to now i just used Dialogflow/Api.ai
I would love to be able to switch on my lights with the Google assistant.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically in that video they are using the [Smart Home integration](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/). There is a sample of the setup flow in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-nodejs)